# Python Data Frame - Compare two rows within a group

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I have a data set like this:

```
GroupID  ItemType   Value
  A        DOG      GREEN
  A        CAT      GREEN
  A        BIRD     BLUE
  B        DOG      ORANGE
  B        CAT      BLUE
  B        BIRD     GREEN
```

What I would like to do is where GroupID is the same, compare Value by for two ItemTypes.  For example, if the Value for DOG and CAT is the same, replace the Value for DOG with NULL.  If the Value for DOG and CAT is not the same, do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I want to use `pd.DataFrame.mask` where `Value` is duplicated... but only within each group defined by `GroupID`.

```
df.groupby('GroupID', group_keys=False).apply(
    lambda d: d.assign(Value=d.Value.mask(d.duplicated('Value', 'last'))))

  GroupID ItemType   Value
0       A      DOG     NaN
1       A      CAT   GREEN
2       A     BIRD    BLUE
3       B      DOG  ORANGE
4       B      CAT    BLUE
5       B     BIRD   GREEN
```